# Code is fine, no error but database is not connected

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am new to sql and I can't understand why this error is showing

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
require = ('./db/conn');

const port = (8800);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("server running on port 8800");
});
```

and this is my conn.js file

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
    user:'root',
    host:'localhost',
    port:'8800',
    password:'',
    database:'liveproject',
});

conn.connect((err)=>{
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database connection successful");
});

module.exports = conn;
```

and this is the output

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
server running on port 8800
```

Database connection is not showing

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This is JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: `require = ('./db/conn');` should be `require('./db/conn');` without the `=`.

Comment: You know what other code is "fine", with "no error"? An empty file. Don't be so quick to point that out, because that's my first thought of your work: the literal equivalent of an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 


// mysql_connect() (dont use this one it's depricated.)


//msqli_connect(hostName,serverName,Password,DBName);
mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1:3307","root","Qwerty-123","users");

$errors = mysqli_connect_error();

if(!$errors)   //checks if it's empty or not. [!string is same as string==""]
{
    echo "Connected to database successfully!";
}
else
{
    echo "There was an error connecting to db.";   
}


?>
```